# Find and replace in word via Excel in Headers and Footers (also)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, headers, footers

I have used this code to find and replace items in column A & B respectively in the Word document. The problem is the code cannot find the items that are on the Headers and footer of the Word document.

Can someone solve this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open "F:\Test folder\TestFolder\Test.docx"
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A

                .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  'Replacements from col B

                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False

                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            Next
        End With
        .Quit SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Word is comprised of a number data layers and they are called Stories. Your current code is searching only the MainTextStory layer. In order for your code to search all layers, you need to incorporate something like my example below:

```
Sub FindInAllStories()
    Dim rng As Word.Range, iShp As Word.InlineShape
    For Each rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Debug.Print rng.StoryType, rng.InlineShapes.Count, rng.ShapeRange.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

If you'd like to search only a particular story ranges, you'd use the StoryType command and specify the specific range you want searched. For a list of the available story types look at this Microsoft article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdstorytype

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to lop through  the sections of your document and put the content in a string and manipulating that:

```
For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each oHeader In oSection.Headers
        Set oRng = oHeader.Range
        myString = oRng.Text
        'manipulate string here

        oRng.Text = myString

        'if you expect text boxes in the headers you must use the following too
        For Each oShp In oHeader.Shapes
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                myString = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                'manipulate string here

            End If
        Next oShp
    Next oHeader
Next oSection
```

You'll need to loop through `oSection.Footers` too

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way for this to work.
I will post the code here:

```
Sub Generar_Informe()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim datos(0 To 1, 0 To 30) As String '(columna,fila)
Dim ruta As String

ruta = "P:\HVBG\Informes\Documentos\INFORME_LHVBG_NEXIB_00X_YY.dotx"
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(ruta)

For j = 0 To UBound(datos, 2)
    datos(0, j) = Hoja1.Cells(j + 4, 1) 'what to find
    datos(1, j) = Hoja1.Cells(j + 4, 2) 'what to replace

    For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges 'loop through

    With wdRng.Find
    .Text = datos(0, j)
    .Replacement.Text = datos(1, j)
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next wdRng

Next j

 Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing
End Sub
```